# Is it acceptable to a paladin of Bahamut to condone the intimate relationship between a silver dragon in dragon form and a red-gold dragonborn

Tags: dnd-5e

Like the Title states.

I'm have a situation where I have a Paladin of Bahamut who learns of an amorous act between a Priestess of Bahamut (in Silver dragon form) and a DragonBorn.

All three are NPCs.

How would the Paladin react?

P.S. don't ask me why; I'm not the DM

Comment: Is there a reason you think it wouldn't just be part of the paladin's character traits to condone it?

Comment: Well, it is between a Dragon(Dragon-form) and a Dragonborn, it might be considered sacrilegious maybe?  i might add that the  Paladin is very by-the-book and has a very religious ,upright character.

Comment: Dragonborn or half-dragon? Also this may be out of scope for this site.

Comment: Dragonborn. I'm not 100% clear on the scope, so sorry if i'm in the wrong place *embarrassed face*

Comment: The DM said that bahamut indeed is fine with that act, i guess the paladin  would have no objection to it haha. Thanks for the insights!

Comment: The correct term is "Rose Gold".

Answer (score 1):

Dragonborn - PHB p.32 (Emphasis mine)

> Born of dragons, as their name proclaims, the dragonborn walk proudly through a world that greets them with fearful incomprehension. **Shaped by draconic gods or the dragons themselves, dragonborn originally hatched from dragon eggs as a unique race, combining the best attributes of dragons and humanoids. Some
>   dragonborn are faithful servants to true dragons**, others form the ranks of soldiers in great wars, and still others find themselves adrift, with no clear calling in life.

Dragonborn basically see Dragons as more pure forms of themselves - as they were created from them, and vice versa, so the Dragon and the Dragonborn are not so different, especially if the Dragon is a priestess.

As for the Paladin, there is too much input to determine the character's reaction - the relationship they have with the other two NPCs, their alignment, their devotion to their god, etc. That being said, as from the excerpt above:

> Shaped by draconic gods or the dragons themselves

There's evidence enough to say that the gods revere Dragonborn just as much as Dragons themselves.

But all in all, there are no hard rules in the roleplaying world. They're more... guidelines.